# Is there a way to detect if the iPhone is in inverse color mode?

Tags: ios, accessibility

You know how in accessibility, the user can set the home button to triple-click and make that the "inverse color mode"? Is there a way for your app to detect if the phone is in the inverse color mode? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, and it's simple. You can call

```
UIAccessibilityIsInvertColorsEnabled();
```

which return a `BOOL` for whether or not inverted colors is currently on.

You can also observe

```
UIAccessibilityInvertColorsStatusDidChangeNotification
```

to get notified when the user turns on or off inverted colors.

Comment: Thanks David. That way I can fix the colors so they still look right in inverted mode.