# iOS Accessibility – Detect if Colour Filters is on?

Tags: ios, accessibility

In iOS, you can set Colour Filters which is helpful for Colour Blind users. Is it possible or any way we can know if this is turned on / off?

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/) does not mention such a thing and there is no  `UIAccessibility` boolean that returns whether color filters are enabled ([unlike for inverted colors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19087042/3151675)), so it's safe to assume that there **isn't a public API** to detect this from an app.

However, this isn't necessarily a problem. Use color schemes in your app in a way that won't distract or confuse users with visual disabilities in the first place.